# MATLAB: ODE45 Events, control the time MATLAB checks events

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have a basic trajectory equation, and I have events stopping `ode45` when it is within a specific distance of a range of points. This works fine most of the time, however, often it just goes straight through the points.

Messing around with the debug tool, I see that the specific events function I created does not run every single time `ode45` calculates a new point, in the situation I've described above it runs it once well before the set distance to stop and then after it has already past through the point to stop. Is there any way I can make sure that it runs the events function after every single timestep?

Comment: Where's your code? There's no way we can help without seeing an example of what you mean. Yes, the events function is called by `ode45` on every time step, so it's not surprising that you see it run before and after where you thought an event should be. If an event is detected the function may be called much more in order to zero in on the location. It sounds like either your events function isn't written properly or your ODE has discontinuous (bad) or stiff behavior in the vicinity of the event. In the latter case you can try adjusting tolerances or using a stiff solver such as `ode15s`.

Comment: Also, note that by default `ode45` returns four data points for each time-step. You can change this either by specifying `tspan` as a vector with more than two values (i.e., fixed step-size output) or via the `'Refine'` option with `odeset`. Your events function is normally only called once per time-step, not once per output point.

Comment: As mentioned by @horchler, what's probably going on is that your event function produces false negatives, probably because it assumes something that isn't always true. Keep in mind that `ode45` is a variable-step solver, meaning that the step can increase to enormous values if the estimated error for that step lies within the current tolerance (e.g., local trajectory is really simple). If your event function checks for sign changes inside a region around the points, or if you only check for left-to-right but the trajectory goes top-to-bottom, or [...], you will get a false negative.